# C++ Random number game from set, rand is choosing a number not from the set

Tags: c++, random

For some reason "0" is being outputted even though I didn't assign it to the set of numbers in the array. How can I get rid of the zero?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int n;
int size=10;
int setNums[10];

int main()
{
    string ans = "";
    do  {
        for (int n=0; n<size;n++ )
        {
            setNums[size] = n+1;\
          cout << setNums[size] << endl;
        }
     srand (time(NULL));
     int choice = rand() % setNums[size];
     cout << choice << endl;
     cout << "Keep guessing?" << endl;
     cin >> ans;
    } while (ans == "Y");

  cout << "\n\n...Press ENTER to Exit System...";
  cin.get();

  return 0;
```

Comment: Side note: `std::iota` does that. Anyway, look closely in your for loop. You sort of do it again with the initialization of `choice` as well. Other side note: why use an array at all? That can easily just be moved to the initialization of `choice`.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: You do realize that you're declaring an array, and then never using any of it except... **one past the end?**

Comment: Don't call `srand()` inside the loop. It only needs to be called __once__ at the top of your `main()` function.

Comment: As a further point, why are you creating an array to begin with?  It looks like all you're doing with it is creating a list of numbers of 1 to size!  Wouldn't it be easier to just constrain the output of rand to an appropriate range, and then adjust it's minimum by adding a value?  (I can be more specific if needed, but this reads as a 'newb needs help' question, and solving it yourself may help you understand the process, as well as the problem -- feel free to ask for more help)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. Yes, this is a noob question. It sucks realizing I have a lot more to learn.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to find the index, not the value itself. Change this:

```
int choice = rand() % setNums[size];
```

to this:

```
int choice = setNums[rand() % size];
```

**Also**, the assignment is always being performed upon the index `size`. You should have:

```
...
for (int n=0; n<size;n++ ) {
    setNums[n] = n+1;\
    cout << setNums[n] << endl;
}
```

Comment: @trem03 Glad it worked! Please, if this post answers your question, accept it as a valid answer, clicking on the tick mark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing `setNums`, and you don't need it at all. Just do this:

```
int choice = rand() % size + 1;
```